# Why don't the elements in the navbar darken like the rest of the page when opening modal? (bootstrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Example: [redacted] - click the Get a Quote button. The navbar elements do not darken.

Also, resize your screen to emulate a phone screen, and you will see that the navbar elements overlap all other elements. How do I solve this as well?

Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Comment: Please show us your code, and not just a link to your site. But my guess would be that the z-index on the navbar is higher than that of the modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.header {
    background: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 1030;
    border: 0px solid #ddd;
    height: 75px;
    position: relative;
}
```

change `z-index` to less than 1040

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue of z-index. Your class .header has z-index more than `.modal`. Try giving

`.header{z-index:1035;}`.

For responsive or mobile view, either you give `.toggled{display:inline-block; width:100%;}` or else remove height from `.header` and `.navbar`.

Hope this helps.
Let me know in case of a query.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to remove the z-index rule from the .header class. It's position is relative and it has 1000+ index.
Second "nav navbar-nav navbar-right bgblue" either remove the class from the ul when clicked  or .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right.bgblue{ background: transparent }